# trying to parse negative monetary amount from string into decimal

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to move the following string "-5017.85" into a decimal variable

I've tried

```
var sAmount = float.Parse(line[1]);
sAmount = decimal.Parse(line[1]);
sAmount = double.Parse(line[1]);
sAmount = decimal.Parse(line[1], NumberStyles.Currency);
sAmount = decimal.Parse(line[1], NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
```

but none work. I get a system.formatexception

what am I missing?

**EDIT**: I had debugged of course and the value is actually: `"\"-5017.85\""` and I assumed the `\`     were escape characters but when I removed them from the variable in watch window then the parsing works just fine. After removing 'escape characters' `"-5017.85"`

**EDIT 2:** this works and give me the correct answer but I do not like it at all

```
line[1].Remove(line[1].Length-1,1).Remove(0,1)
```

any better ways of doing this?

Comment: What is `line`?  If it's a string, you are trying to parse a single character.

Comment: sorry.  line is a string array

Comment: Are you sure that the string at index 1 contains "-5017.85"? Could it be located at index 0 instead? Try inserting a breakpoint, debug and see what line really contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like your string contains an unnecessary " character. You can remove it like so, using [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
sAmount = decimal.Parse(line[1].Replace("\"", ""));
```

Comment: I just found this myself  and was about to post line[1].Replace("\"", string.Empty) but you beat me to it...hehe..I'll mark your as answer

Comment: I say "", you say string.Empty. Tomato, tomahto. :)

Answer (score 3):

Something is clearly not right here, I suspect that `line[1]` is not what you think it is. Are you *sure* that `line[1] == "-5017.85"` is `true`?

Another possible scenario that you have a different culture setting that is preventing `-` from being parsed as the optional sign character or `.` as the decimal-point separator, but this is an unlikely scenarios.

If you're sure that `line[1] == "-5017.85"` is `true`, could you please try

```
var sAmount = Decimal.Parse(
    line[1],
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

and report back.

> I had debugged of course and the value is actually: `"\"-5017.85\""`

Well, in that case, I'd merely use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) to replace the `\"` characters with the empty string as in:

```
var sAmount = Decimal.Parse(line[1].Replace("\"", ""));
```

Comment: thanks. See my edit for value. There was escape characters in value

Comment: @kurasa: Just use `String.Replace`; please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `double.Parse(line[1].Trim());`; it seems there are non-numeric, white space characters there.